# "Drone Racer" now shipping in your local area

Tags: python, python-3.x, console, factory-method, i18n

This question is a follow-up of [this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/115181/84718); where I present a software to plan and manage drone races. I might come with a new question about the SQL part in a few days as well.
The code can still be browsed [on GitHub](https://github.com/Kniyl/Drone-Racer/tree/870948a90dce455a3e2895f04c90f3ca64470c18).

Since then, on top of the changes in documentation that I made in [my own answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/115568/84718), I included the [`gettext` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html) and changed the CLI to include sub-commands.

On top of the previous ones, I'm a little bit concerned about the layout of my project since I basically put everything in a single directory:

```
+ droneracer.py
+ drone_racer
  + fr
  | + LC_MESSAGES
  |   + cli.po
  |   + cli.mo
  |   + utils.po
  |   + utils.mo
  + __init__.py
  + console.py
  + i18n.py
  + rest.py
  + sql.py
  + threads.py
  + ui.py
```

The program invocation now looks like one of the following:

- `python droneracer.py --fancy-title xbee /dev/ttyUSB0`
- `python droneracer.py udp --port 3487`
- `python droneracer.py --fancy-title`

The code became:

**droneracer.py**

```
"""Drone Racer is a project primarily developed for the DroneFest
organized as part of the FabLab Festival 2015. Its aim is to provide
an all-in-one interface for races organizers to:

  - create different events for drones competition;
  - register contestants and their associated drones;
  - classify drones into categories;
  - create several routes with their own set of rules for each event;
  - setup and monitor races on a designated route;
  - gather statistics on races for drivers, event or kind of route.

To reduce the overhead of having extraneous services for database
access, Drone Racer makes use of the python's built-in sqlite module.
It uses it to store informations on the contestants, the drones, the
different type of routes and the races leaderboards.

Additionally, setup, updates & leaderboard for each race can be sent
to a RESTful API for the audience.
"""


import os

from argparse import ArgumentParser
from drone_racer.i18n import translations
import drone_racer


_, _N = translations('cli')
XBEE_NAMES = 'xbee', 'bee', 'serial'
UDP_NAMES = 'udp', 'wifi'


parser = ArgumentParser(description=_('"Drone Racer"\'s Graphical User Interface'))
parser.add_argument(
        '--fancy-title', dest='fancy', action='store_true',
        help=_('Use a fancier (Gtk3 like) titlebar for the GUI'))
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(
        title='communication', dest='reader', description=_('List off all '
        'communication channels to get data from the gates. If none is '
        'selected, data will be read from stdin.'), metavar='DATA_LINK',
        help=_('More options are available per channel'))

name, *aliases = XBEE_NAMES
bee_parser = subparsers.add_parser(
        name, aliases=aliases, help=_('Communication through XBee frames'))
bee_parser.add_argument(
        'device', metavar='FILE', default=None,
        help=_('Serial file mapped to the XBee pins'))
bee_parser.add_argument(
        '--zigbee', dest='zigbee', action='store_true',
        help=_('Switch indicating wether it is an XBee or a ZigBee'))
bee_parser.add_argument(
        '--baudrate', dest='baudrate', metavar='BPS', type=int, default=9600,
        help=_('Serial port communication speed'))

name, *aliases = UDP_NAMES
udp_parser = subparsers.add_parser(
        name, aliases=aliases, help=_('Communication through UDP datagrams'))
udp_parser.add_argument(
        '--port', dest='port', metavar='NUM', type=int, default=4387,
        help=_('Socket port to listen on'))

# Choose the appropriate reader
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.reader in XBEE_NAMES:
    reader = drone_racer.XBeeReader(
            args.serial, args.baudrate, zigbee=args.zigbee)
elif args.reader in UDP_NAMES:
    reader = drone_racer.UDPReader(args.port)
else:
    reader = drone_racer.StdInReader()

# Be sure to be at the right place for relative path of images in Gtk
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Launch the GUI (which will, in turn, start the reader)
app = drone_racer.Application(reader, args.fancy)
app.run()
```

**drone_racer/__init__.py**

```
"""Pubilc interface to the various components defined in this package.

Allows to construct the GUI responsible of the whole application
and to select a reader from the built-in ones.
"""


from .ui import DroneRacer as Application
from .threads import StdInReader, XBeeReader, UDPReader


__all__ = [
    'Application',
    'StdInReader',
    'XBeeReader',
    'UDPReader',
]
```

**drone_racer/i18n.py**

```
import os.path
import gettext

def translations(domain):
    locales_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    translation = gettext.translation(domain, locales_dir)
    return translation.gettext, translation.ngettext
```

**drone_racer/threads.py**

```
"""Collection of classes to crete threaded objects allowing to read
data from various sources.

Readers should be created with whatever parameter they require and
then allow to be called with a callback function. This call return
the threaded object reading data.

These threaded objects are started immediatly and monitor incomming
data to normalize them before feeding them into the callback function.
They can easily be halted using their `stop` method.
"""


import os
import sys
import socket
from threading import Thread
from select import select
try:
    from serial import Serial
    from xbee import XBee, ZigBee
except ImportError:
    XBee = None

from .i18n import translations


_, _N = translations('utils')


class BaseReader(Thread):
    """Base class for custom data readers."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Spawn a thread that will continuously read data for drones
        statuses.
        """
        super().__init__(name="reader")

    def __call__(self, update_function):
        """Starts the thread with the given callback function to
        process data with.

        Parameter:
          - update_function: the function that will be called each time
            a valid data is read.
        """
        self._update_data = update_function
        self._should_continue = True
        self.start()
        # Return ourselves to allow for duck typing and other classes
        # to return other kind of objects (see XBeeReader).
        return self

    def run(self):
        """The main action of the thread.

        Wait for data, read them and send them to the rest of the
        application for further computation.
        """
        while self._should_continue:
            try:
                gate, drone = self.read_new_value()
            except TypeError:
                pass
            else:
                self._process_value(gate, drone)

    def stop(self):
        """Signal that the thread has to stop reading its inputs."""
        self._should_continue = False

    def read_new_value(self):
        """Read input data and return them as a tuple (gate identifier,
        drone number). Subclasses must implement this method.
        """
        raise NotImplementedError(_("Subclasses must implement this method"))

    def _process_value(self, gate, drone):
        """Send input data to the rest of the application.

        Parameters:
          - gate: the gate identification letter(s)
          - drone: the drone identification number (0-based)
        """
        if drone < 0:
            return
        self._update_data(gate, drone)


class StdInReader(BaseReader):
    """Read data from stdin. Primarily used for tests and debug."""

    def read_new_value(self):
        """Read input data and return them as a tuple (gate identifier,
        drone number).

        Convert data such as "0 1" to the tuple ('A', 1).
        """
        raw = input('[@] ').split()
        try:
            gate, drone = raw
            return chr(int(gate) + ord('A')), int(drone)
        except ValueError:
            pass


class UDPReader(BaseReader):
    """Read data from UDP datagrams. Used when communicating via
    WiFi with the gates.
    """

    def __init__(self, port):
        """Spawn a thread that continuously read data for drones
        statuses.

        Parameter:
          - port: the socket port to listen on.
        """
        super().__init__()
        com = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        iface = socket.gethostname()
        com.bind((iface, port))
        self._socket = [com]

    def read_new_value(self):
        """Read input data and return them as a tuple (gate identifier,
        drone number).

        Decode an UDP datagram containing b"C:3" to the tuple ('C', 2).
        """
        # Non-blocking read so this thread will shut down with the application
        ready, _, _ = select(self._socket, [], [], 0.05)
        for socket in ready:
            msg = socket.recv(128) # Way too much for messages like <A:1>
            try:
                gate, drone = msg.split(b':')
                gate = gate.decode()
                # Compensate for the drone numbering vs. its indexing
                drone = int(drone) - 1
            except (UnicodeError, ValueError) as e:
                print(_('Received unparsable message: {}').format(msg),
                        file=sys.stderr)
                print(e, file=sys.stderr)
            else:
                return gate, drone


if XBee is None:
    class XBeeReader(BaseReader):
        """Read data from a serial port bound to an XBee.
        Dummy implementation because xbee module could not be loaded.
        """

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            """Accepts arguments to be compatible with the "real"
            XBeeReader but prints a warning and terminate gracefully
            instead.
            """
            super().__init__()
            print(_('Can not load XBee module. No data will be received'),
                    file=sys.stderr)

        def read_new_value(self):
            """Cancel this thread to avoid burning resources."""
            self._should_continue = False

else:
    class _BeeReaderMixin:
        """Read data from a serial port bound to an XBee."""

        def __init__(self, serial, callback):
            """Initialize the XBee reader thanks to the mro.

            Parameters:
              - serial: the serial port object to read data from
              - callback: the function that will be called each
                time a valid data is read.
            """
            self._update_data = callback
            super().__init__(serial, callback=self._process_value)

        def _process_value(self, response_dict):
            """Convert a raw data received in a frame by the XBee
            into suitable data for the application.

            Should be called each time a frame is read by the XBee.
            """
            try:
                gate, drone = response_dict['rf_data'].split(b':')
                gate = gate.decode()
                # Compensate for the drone numbering vs. its indexing
                drone = int(drone) - 1
            except (UnicodeError, ValueError) as e:
                print(_('Received unparsable message: {}').format(
                        response_dict['rf_data']), file=sys.stderr)
                print(e, file=sys.stderr)
            except KeyError as e:
                print(_('Received empty frame'), file=sys.stderr)
                print(e, file=sys.stderr)
            else:
                self._update_data(gate, drone)

        def stop(self):
            """Halt the thread from reading its input and close the
            underlying serial port.
            """
            self.halt()
            self.serial.close()


    class XBeeReader:
        """Wrapper around the xbee module to integrate our
        _BeeReaderMixin into the appropriate base class.
        """

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            """Save parameters for future use.

            Every parameter is used to initialize a serial.Serial
            object except for the named attribute 'zigbee' which
            define the base class to use.

            Parameter:
              - zigbee: whether to use the xbee.ZigBee base class or
                the xbee.XBee one
            """
            zigbee = kwargs.pop('zigbee', False)
            base_cls = ZigBee if zigbee else XBee
            self._serial = Serial(*args, **kwargs)
            self._cls = type('XBeeReader', (_BaseReaderMixin, base_cls), {})

        def __call__(self, callback):
            """Generate the appropriate object to read data.

            Parameter:
              - callback: the function that will be called each
                time a valid data is read.
            """
            return self._cls(self._serial, callback)
```

Comment: Are you actually importing `_` as a callable? That seems terribly dodgy to me, why not give it a real name?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Because it is kind of [a convention](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html#gettext.install) when using gettext. It is also used like that [in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-python-code) for instance. I contemplated using `tr()` instead of `_()`; but the simplicity of using tools to manage gettext-aware code had me choose the latter.

Comment: Ah I see, the point is to be unnoticeable especially as it's called on so many strings. That makes sense.

Comment: You have a typo in the docstring of drone_racer/__init__.py (pubilc -> public)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### i18n

This is just me, but I've always found the `_` and `_N` aspect of `gettext` a little hard to read and somewhat too tightly coupled.  I've always preferred something like this:

i18n.py

```
import os.path
import gettext

def _translations(domain):
    locales_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    translation = gettext.translation(domain, locales_dir)
    return translation.gettext, translation.ngettext

class _BaseTranslator(object):

    @staticmethod
    def _translations(domain):
        locales_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
        translation = gettext.translation(domain, locales_dir)
        return translation.gettext, translation.ngettext

    def __init__(self, domain):
        self.domain = domain
        self._, self._N = self._translations(domain)

class _CliTranslations(_BaseTranslator):

    def __init__(self, domain='cli'):
        super().__init__(domain)

    @property
    def description(self):
        return self._('"Drone Racer"\'s Graphical User Interface')

    # etc

util_translations = _UtilTranslations('util')
cli_translations = _CliTranslations('cli')
```

cli.py

```
from i18n import cli_translations as cli

parser = ArgumentParser(description=cli.description)
```

I understand that it isn't for everyone, but I've always preferred that the original strings be less embedded in the source code, and instead be in the translating engine.  I actually prefer it even more if they aren't in the source code at all, but rather in some JSON or XML file (or whatever your preferred format is). By putting all of the strings into the translating engine instead, you make it much easier to change where and how the strings and their translations are stored and received, and you don't have to change the source of any of the other files.

If you don't like that they're instances, you can do [some hackery for class-level properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1735434/3076272) - I've never found a satisfying way to implement that where the properties aren't read-only, but in this context you want them to be read-only (win-win).

### Reader classes

#### Subclassing `Thread`

Your implementation of your reader classes make me a little uncomfortable. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects)

> No other methods (except for the constructor) should be overridden in a subclass. In other words, only override the `__init__()` and `run()` methods of this class.

Now, currently, I don't see anything in them that actually overrides anything in the `Thread` class, however I would be mindful of this in case a future Python version changes it (tbh I don't see that happening, but it's worth being considerate of).

It seems that you don't actually need your readers to subclass `Thread` - what about making each of them callable objects instead, and then set them as the targets of the threads?  Then you'll avoid any of these potential issues, and avoid having to muck around with `Thread` too much.

#### Signalling

Instead of using a boolean to determine if the reader should continue, use the appropriate concurrency primitive, in this case [`threading.Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Event).

#### [`dummy_threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dummy_threading.html#module-dummy_threading)

I don't know what sort of machines you're running this on, but if there's any chance that `_thread` won't be available you should have something like

> ```
> try:
>     import threading
> except ImportError:
>     import dummy_threading as threading
> ```

#### Appropriate errors

`_process_value` seems like it should do something if the drone id is less than 0 - probably emit some warning for the user so they know that they, or someone else, has done something wrong. The only reason to just `return` is if you either don't think it'll ever happen, or if ignoring it is fine. It seems that it would probably be indicative of some larger problem though, one that the operator/officiator/someone should be aware of.

Likewise, in `run` you ignore `TypeError`s - why?  Again, unless they can be safely ignored and wouldn't be either unusual or unexpected you should at least give some sort of warning that something unusual might be going on.

#### Typo?

Should this say `_BeeReaderMixin`?  Or are you trying to incorporate `BaseReader`? Some combination thereof?

```
self._cls = type('XBeeReader', (_BaseReaderMixin, base_cls), {})
```

The whole `XBeeReader` seems like it could be incorporated into a metaclass and then used that way instead of how you have implemented it, but metaclasses aren't my forte.

Comment: Thanks for the typos, will edit ASAP. Interesting thoughts overall, too. About the errors, I should be able to remove `_process_value` since the callback data already check for the proper range (and print messages there); I needed it because I used to return `-1, '?'` for invalid data in `read_new_value`. Now that I return `None` I need to catch `TypeError` for the unpacking instead. Will add a comment to highlight that.

Comment: And for the threading part: both `xbee.XBee` and `xbee.ZigBee` are already subclasses of `Thread`. I built around that to get a consistent interface. Do you feel like there could be a better way? Also what are the advantages of `Event` (flag + wait) here over a simple boolean (flag)? I don't need to _wait_ until the flag is set, I need to _work_ (monitor communication) until the flag is set.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger If they're already subclasses of `Thread` then I wouldn't change it.  I'd say the biggest advantage of `Event` would be that you could more easily coordinate multiple readers, if you needed them.  Additionally, I generally prefer things designed to work with concurrency (such as `Event`) than the language defaults (such as booleans), but that's a personal preference.  If you set the flag before starting, then you don't wait until it's set, you just work as long as it is set.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the timeout facilities built into the `socket` module instead of using `select.select`. Basically, you can call `settimeout(amount)` on any `socket` created and each blocking operation on that socket will raise `socket.timeout` exception after the specified `amount` of seconds if the operation did not complete.

Your `UDPReader` can thus look like:

```
class UDPReader(BaseReader):
    """Read data from UDP datagrams. Used when communicating via
    WiFi with the gates.
    """

    def __init__(self, port):
        """Spawn a thread that continuously read data for drones
        statuses.

        Parameter:
          - port: the socket port to listen on.
        """
        super().__init__()
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        iface = socket.gethostname()
        self.socket.bind((iface, port))
        # Non-blocking read so this thread will shut down with the application
        self.socket.settimeout(1)

    def read_new_value(self):
        """Read input data and return them as a tuple (gate identifier,
        drone number).

        Decode an UDP datagram containing b"C:3" to the tuple ('C', 2).
        """
        try:
            msg = self.socket.recv(128) # Way too much for messages like <A:1>
        except socket.timeout:
            return
        try:
            gate, drone = msg.split(b':')
            gate = gate.decode()
            # Compensate for the drone numbering vs. its indexing
            drone = int(drone) - 1
        except (UnicodeError, ValueError) as e:
            print(_('Received unparsable message: {}').format(msg),
                    file=sys.stderr)
            print(e, file=sys.stderr)
        else:
            return gate, drone
```