# Multi-lang support for names of playing cards

Tags: python, python-3.x, playing-cards, enum, i18n

*Context:*

Coming from C# I am building a python 3.6 texas hold'em to get acquainted with different python features.

I am currently buidling `enums` for card-colors and -faces and classes for cards and DeckOfCards etc.

```
DeckOfCards -> 52 * Card -> (CardColor, CardFace)
```

I want the cards to print themself using different ("en","de", ..) languages. Each class has its own dict of languages and some setLang/getLang method to change it. Each class `__str__()` uses the dict to output itself differently depending on the `__lang__` set for each class.

`setLang(..)`propagates down from `DeckOfCards`->`Card`->`CardColor`->`CardFace` - this is *tedious*.

I was considering a "global" Translater for all classes that can be used inside each class’s `self.__str__` method.

#### **How would one provide multi-lang support 'usually' in python?**

remarks:

- I glanced through PEP 8 but I am not going 100% conform with it - using my C# style mostly
- I haven't found a suitable tag for multi-lang, globalisation or translation

---

**CardColor**

```
from enum import Enum,unique

@unique
class CardColor(Enum):
    Pikes = 4  
    Hearts = 3  
    Tiles = 2  
    Clovers = 1 

    __lang__ = "de"

    __nameDict__ = { "de" : {Pikes: "Pik", Hearst: "Herz", Tiles: "Karo", Clovers: "Kreuz"},
                     "en" : {Pikes: "Pikes", Hearst: "Hearts", Tiles:"Tiles", Clovers: "Clovers"} }
    
    def getLang(self):
        '''returns available languages'''
        return self.__nameDict__.keys()[:] 

    def setLang(self, lang):
        '''sets the language of this instance'''
        if lang in self.__nameDict__:
            self.__lang__ = lang
    
    def __str__(self):
        '''returns the DisplayName'''
        return '{0}'.format(self.__nameDict__[self.__lang__][self.value])
```

---

**CardFace**

```
from enum import Enum,unique

@unique
class CardFace(Enum):
    Two = 2 
    Three = 3
    Four = 4
    Five = 5
    Six = 6
    Seven = 7
    Eight = 8
    Nine = 9
    Ten = 10
    Jack = 11
    Queen = 12
    King = 13
    Ace = 14  

    __lang__ = ""
    __nameDict__ = { "de" : {    Two : "Zwei", Three : "Drei", Four : "Vier", Five : "Fünf", Six : "Sechs", Seven : "Sieben", Eight : "Acht", 
                                Nine : "Neun", Ten : "Zehn", Jack : "Bube", Queen : "Dame", King : "König", Ace : "As" },
                     "en" : {    Two : "Two", Three : "Three", Four : "Four", Five : "Five", Six : "Six", Seven : "Seven", Eight : "Eight",
                                 Nine : "Nine", Ten : "Ten", Jack : "Jack",Queen : "Queen",King : "King", Ace : "Ace"} } 

    def getLang(self):
        '''returns available languages'''
        return self.__nameDict__.keys() 

    def setLang(self, lang):
        '''sets the language of this instance'''
        if lang in self.__nameDict__:
            self.__lang__ = lang

    def __str__(self):
        '''returns the DisplayName'''
        return '{0}'.format(self.__nameDict__.get(self.__lang__, self.__nameDict__.get('en'))[self.value])
```

---

**Card**

```
from enum import Enum,unique
from cardcolor import CardColor
from cardface import CardFace
 
class Card:
    __lang__ = "de"
    __nameDict__ = { "de" : "{1} {0}", "en" : "{0} of {1}"} 


    def __init__(self, cardColor, cardValue):
        self.c = cardColor
        self.v = cardValue 

    def __str__(self):
        '''returns the cards DisplayName'''
        return self.__nameDict__.get(self.__lang__, self.__nameDict__.get('en')).format(self.v, self.c)
      
    def setLang(self, lang):
        if (lang in self.__nameDict__) and lang in self.v.getLang() and lang in self.c.getLang() :
            self.__lang__ = lang
            self.v.setLang(lang) 
            self.c.setLang(lang)
```

---

**DeckOfCards**

```
from card import Card
from cardcolor import CardColor
from cardface import CardFace
from random import shuffle
    
class DeckOfCards:
    __lang__ = ""
    __nameDict__ = { "de" : "Kartenspiel", "en" : "Deck of Cards"} 

    __deck__ = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.__deck__= self.__newDeck__()
        self.__shuffle__()

    def __shuffle__(self):
        shuffle(self.__deck__)

    def __newDeck__(self):
        return [Card(c,v) for c in CardColor for v in CardFace]

    def __str__(self):
        '''returns the cards DisplayName''' 
        return "{0}:\n    {1}{2}".format(self.__nameDict__.get(self.__lang__, self.__nameDict__.get('en')),
                                      ''.join([', '.join([str(c) for c in self.__deck__[x:x+6]])+',\n    ' for x in range(0,len(self.__deck__), 6) ]).strip().strip(",\n"),
                                      "\n")
      
    def Cards(self):
        return  self.__deck__[:]

    def setLang(self, lang):
        if (lang in self.__nameDict__): # Todo: check if all support lang
            self.__lang__ = lang
            for c in self.__deck__:
                c.setLang(lang) 

    @staticmethod
    def printOneShuffledDeck(lang=None):
        d = DeckOfCards() 
        if lang:
            d.setLang(lang)
        print(d)
```

---

To generate printouts for testing:

```
from deckofcards import DeckOfCards

DeckOfCards.printOneShuffledDeck("en") 
DeckOfCards.printOneShuffledDeck("de")
```

Output:

```
Deck of Cards:
    Jack of Hearts, Nine of Hearts, King of Diamonds, Eight of Hearts, Seven of Diamonds, Eight of Clovers,
    Five of Hearts, Six of Clovers, Seven of Pikes, Nine of Clovers, Six of Hearts, Three of Diamonds,
    Five of Clovers, Eight of Diamonds, Three of Pikes, Six of Diamonds, Three of Clovers, Ten of Pikes,
    Three of Hearts, Jack of Pikes, Five of Diamonds, Eight of Pikes, Queen of Diamonds, Two of Pikes,
    Queen of Hearts, Ace of Hearts, Two of Diamonds, Five of Pikes, Four of Diamonds, Four of Clovers,
    Seven of Clovers, Two of Clovers, Nine of Pikes, Ten of Hearts, Queen of Clovers, Six of Pikes,
    King of Hearts, King of Clovers, Ten of Diamonds, Four of Hearts, Ace of Clovers, Two of Hearts,
    Jack of Clovers, Queen of Pikes, Ace of Diamonds, King of Pikes, Nine of Diamonds, Jack of Diamonds,
    Ace of Pikes, Four of Pikes, Ten of Clovers, Seven of Hearts

Kartenspiel:
    Karo König, Pik Sieben, Herz Vier, Pik As, Kreuz Bube, Herz Bube,
    Herz Fünf, Herz Sieben, Pik Sechs, Pik Acht, Herz Dame, Karo Neun,
    Kreuz Drei, Karo Zwei, Karo Zehn, Kreuz König, Karo Sieben, Kreuz Neun,
    Kreuz As, Pik König, Karo Acht, Herz Sechs, Karo Bube, Pik Zehn,
    Kreuz Sieben, Kreuz Zwei, Herz As, Karo Drei, Karo As, Pik Drei,
    Herz König, Pik Dame, Kreuz Fünf, Pik Vier, Herz Zwei, Pik Fünf,
    Kreuz Acht, Herz Neun, Pik Zwei, Kreuz Zehn, Kreuz Dame, Karo Fünf,
    Herz Zehn, Kreuz Sechs, Kreuz Vier, Herz Drei, Karo Sechs, Karo Dame,
    Herz Acht, Pik Neun, Pik Bube, Karo Vier
```

Comment: This question is off-topic ( asking about code not yet written ). Also: don't create your own magic methods!

Comment: `glanced through PEP 8` check whether your IDE supports PEP 8 hinting (much the same way the spelling checker you don't seem to be using would). Have a look at [docstring/PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), too.

Comment: @Coal_ If I would have been sure about that, I would have close voted instead of editing. The OP has a working solution of what they want to achieve, and asks if there are better ways to do that in python in essence.

Comment: @Coal_ What I have works, it is just tedious - and there may be smarter ways to do it - what I thought that codereview is about...

Comment: @greybeard I am using VS2017 for python as well as C# - it was pointed outto me that there are python specific IDEs - VS does not seem to know  about either PEP nor provide rules/warnings - but VS is what I am using atm. What do mean with spelling checker?

Comment: I once asked a [question about localization](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/116169/84718) and got good insights.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger bookmarked the read, looks great. going to investigate `metaclass`es and  module `gettext`

Comment: `spelling checker`: have your computer warn you about `aquainted`, `buidling`, `themselfs`, `Translater`, `eachs`, `throuhg`, `stlye`, `havent`, `mulit`, even `color` guessing you learned English closer to Merry Old than to God Bless.

Comment: @greybeard now I get it - its my 2nd lang and I read a lot of fantasy in it ;) thanks will go over it. PEP257 is a good tip, need to reformulate almost any docstring

Comment: Normally Python can use libraries like gettext ( https://docs.python.org/2/library/gettext.html ) or babel ( http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/ ), so there is no need to write translations directly in the code.

Comment: @RomanSusi new to pythonian ways - gettext I already got from the comment of Mathias Ettinger, babel I only know from Latex - will read up on it as well, thanks

Comment: @PatrickArtner Metaclasses? It's probably not good way without knowing Python much better first.

Answer (score 5):

## Dunder Methods

I'd drop the double-underscores in most of your methods. These conventions are usually reserved for magic methods, of which are things like `__dict__`, `__str__`, `__iadd__`, etc. Otherwise, underscores are used to separate names in instances of inheritance, which is not the case here. In your case, it impairs readability and makes other developers have to guess "is this *really* a magic method?"

## Naming Variables

Variable names should be separated by underscores, such as `lang_dict` instead of `langDict`.

## Getting keys from `dict`

Iterating over a `dict` returns the keys, no need to manually call `dict.keys()` when you can do `list(some_dict)` or `', '.join(some_dict)`. Also, `dict.keys` is like a `set`, so it is not able to be sliced and the call `some_dict.keys()[:]` should raise a `TypeError`

## Building Your Language Dictionaries

`Enum` is built on `OrderedDict`. The beautiful part? It's ordered based on the item insertion in the enum:

```py
from enum import Enum

class CardColor(Enum):
    Pikes = 4  
    Hearts = 3  
    Tiles = 2  
    Clovers = 1 

', '.join(CardColor.__members__)
# Pikes, Hearts, Tiles, Clovers
```

With this in mind, you don't have to keep repeating your call to the respective field names, use the `dict` constructor with `zip` against your translation. Also, I'd call this enum `CardSuit`, since `CardColor` would imply `Red` or `Black`:

```py
from enum import Enum

class CardSuit(Enum):

    Pikes = 4  
    Hearts = 3  
    Tiles = 2  
    Clovers = 1 

    __lang_dict__ = {
        'de': dict(zip(CardSuit.__members__, ('Pik', 'Herz', 'Karo', 'Kreuz'))),
        'en': dict(zip(CardSuit.__members__, ('Pikes', 'Hearts', 'Tiles', 'Clovers')))
    }
```

Much less typing.

## Default `lang`

I'd set a default lang, as you have already, on the instance as a keyword arg, and when `set_lang` is called, do a check against the keys in the dictionary and `raise ValueError` otherwise:

```py
class Card:
    lang_dict = { "de" : "{1} {0}", "en" : "{0} of {1}"} 

    def __init__(self, card_color, card_value, lang='de'):
        self.c = card_color
        self.v = card_value 
        # We can set this here, but this will be overruled when setting
        # the language at the deck level, this is done *after*
        # c and v are set on self
        self.lang = lang if lang == 'de' else self.set_lang(lang)


    def __str__(self):
        '''returns the cards DisplayName'''
        # You shouldn't have to use a .get here, since on set_lang
        # it already checks for a valid key
        return self.lang_dict[self.lang].format(self.v, self.c)


    def set_lang(self, lang):
        lang = lang.lower().strip()
        if lang not in self.lang_dict:
            raise ValueError(
              f"Tried to set invalid lang in Card, expected one of "
              f"{', '.join(self.lang_dict)}, got {lang}"
            )
        self.lang = lang
        self.c.set_lang(lang)
        self.v.set_lang(lang)
```

And on the `Enum` types, since you need the dunder var names to avoid them being options. Note the refactor on `__str__` here:

```py
class CardSuit(Enum):

    Pikes = 4  
    Hearts = 3  
    Tiles = 2  
    Clovers = 1 

    __lang_dict__ = {
        'de': dict(zip(CardSuit.__members__, ('Pik', 'Herz', 'Karo', 'Kreuz'))),
        'en': dict(zip(CardSuit.__members__, ('Pikes', 'Hearts', 'Tiles', 'Clovers')))
    }
    __lang__ = 'de'

    def get_langs(self):
        # will get all the keys for you, though I'm not sure you need this?
        return list(self.__lang_dict__)

    def set_lang(self, lang):
        if lang not in self.__lang_dict__:
            raise ValueError(
              f"Tried to set invalid lang in CardSuit, expected one of "
              f"{', '.join(self.__lang_dict__)}, got {lang}"
            )
        self.__lang__ = lang

    def __str__(self):
        # re-factoring this for clarity
        # I think f-strings are nice here, however,
        # you might decide to keep the .format convention
        # since you use it in Card, which works well
        return f'{self.__lang_dict__[self.__lang__].value}'
```

Now, looking at the deck:

```py
class DeckOfCards:
    lang_dict = { "de" : "Kartenspiel", "en" : "Deck of Cards"}

    # set a default here of 'de'
    def __init__(self, lang='de'):
        self.lang = lang.lower().strip()
        if self.lang not in self.lang_dict:
            raise ValueError(f'Got invalid lang, expected one of {", ".join(self.lang_dict)}, got {self.lang}')

        # note we are dropping all underscores here
        self.deck = self.new_deck()
        self.shuffle()


    def set_lang(self, lang):
        """
        Set a language at the deck level that propogates through the child
        classes.
        """
        # grab a default to roll back with
        # in case a non-supported language is chosen
        _lang = self.lang

        for i, card in enumerate(self.deck):
            try:
                card.set_lang(lang)
            except ValueError as e:
                print(e)
                break
        else:
            self.lang = lang
            return

        # set back to default by traversing backward through
        # indices, then you can set mismatching dictionaries
        # and it will still only handle where the languages
        # line up
        while i >= 0:
            self.deck[i].set_lang(_lang)
            i -= 1
```

## Refactoring `__str__`

Now, the one area that I think will clean up `__str__` on the `DeckOfCards` class is using `zip` to pair up slice-points:

```py
    def __str__(self):
        # I've pulled these out of the comprehension for readability
        slice_start = range(0, len(self.deck), 6)    # 0, 6, 12, ..., 48
        slice_end = range(6, len(self.deck) + 6, 6)  # 6, 12, ..., 54

        # You could do this in fewer lines, but I think the explicitness
        # is better for the example. Again, I like the f-string here,
        # but you can decide if you want to retain str.format
        dict_str = f'{self.lang_dict[self.lang]}:\n\t'
        a = '\n\t'.join(
                  ', '.join(map(str, self.deck[i:j])) for i, j
                  in zip(slice_start, slice_end))

       return dict_str + a
```

Again, the point here being that you shouldn't be leaning on `.get` inside the method because it is expected that the language was checked ahead of time.

## `DeckOfCards.deck`

The `NewDeck` should be re-named and whitespace should be inserted between variables/operators. Also, you can have the `self.lang` applied to each `Card` so you can select the language on creation of the `Deck`, rather than only using a default and having to switch it every time:

```py
    # functions should be snake-case
    def new_deck(self):
        # include whitespaces between variables in Card declaration
        return [Card(c, v, self.lang) for c in CardColor for v in CardFace]
```

## `Deck.Cards`?

You don't need this method, you already have a deck of cards. Just do a lookup on `self.deck`, it's also already a list, so no need to slice

## `PrintOneShuffledDeck`

This should be a standalone method, IMO, not a `staticmethod` on a class. You can refactor it by just printing the created instance:

```py
# this default matches the default for the other classes
print_shuffled_deck(lang='de'):
    print(DeckOfCards(lang))
```

And because of the refactor in how `set_lang` is implemented, you don't need to call `set_lang` externally here, you can specify the language you want at the time of deck creation.

## Final Caveat

Only issue here is that because `Enum` doesn't give you an *instance*, your binding of `__lang__` will hold individually for options, but not between decks. To show you what I mean:

```py
from enum import Enum

class X(Enum):
    A = 1,
    B = 2
    __var__ = 1

a = X.A
b = X.B

a.__var__ += 1

print(b.__var__)
1

print(a.__var__)
2

print(X.A.__var__)
2
```

Not sure how much that matters to you in your use-case, but figured I'd highlight it anyways. You can't have more than one deck if you want each deck to support a different language.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and multiple good suggestions - gotta mull over them a bit